# Clarification about a theorem

Tags: real-analysis

This is the Theorem:

**2.4.4 Corollary** *If* $s:=\{1/n\,:\,n\in\mathbb{N}\},$ *then* $\inf S=0.$

***Proof.*** Since $S\not=\varnothing$ is bounded below by $0$, it has an infimum and we let $w:=\inf S$. It is clear that $w\ge 0.$ For any $\varepsilon>0,$ the Archimedean Property implies that there exists $n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $1/\varepsilon < n$, which implies $1/n<\varepsilon$. Therefore we have
$$0\le w\le 1/n <\varepsilon.$$
But since $\varepsilon>0$ is arbitrary, it follows from Theorem 2.1.9 that $w=0$. Q.E.D.

My question is that the quantified statement:
For every $\epsilon$ > 0, P(n)
is not the same as :
P(n), for every $\epsilon$ >0
for example, 
0 $\leqslant$ x < $\epsilon$ for every $\epsilon$ >0 $\Rightarrow$ $x=0$

however, for every $\epsilon$ > 0, 0 $\leqslant$ x < $\epsilon$ does not imply $x=0$

why the author concluded that $w=0$ ? because for every positive number $m$, we must have another number n such that $0<n<m$

Thanks

Comment: why the author conclude w=0 !

Comment: Could you write a specific question that is distinct from various observations and other things? I don't know what you are asking. Indeed, you never used a question mark for punctuation, so technically you have not asked a question. Yes, I know my last sentence is going a bit overboard, but this is just an example of how incomplete your question is.

Comment: Why do you think that does not imply $x=0$? If you know it's not true, give us a counterexample. In the question you haven't even said what $x$ is though, so that may be the source of confusion. Of course there is *some* $x\neq 0$ for each $\epsilon > 0$ satisfying $0 \leq x<\epsilon$, but that's not the setting in the proof. Is that your confusion?

Comment: Dave, edited! and open the picture

Comment: Alex, he built the conclusion $w=0$ on a wrong foundation

Comment: What wrong foundation? As per your edit, the $w$ in the proof is a fixed number, you don't get to pick a different $w$ for each value of $n$, and if the inequality is satisfied for any possible choice of $n$, then $w$ must be 0.

Comment: Unless I'm overlooking a math typo or something similar that I'm "blind to" (but which a person new to this isn't blind to), the argument basically comes down to proving $w \geq 0$ and $w \leq 0,$ which implies $w = 0.$ The first inequality follows from the fact that $w$ has to be greater than any negative number and the second from the fact that $w$ has to be less than any positive number.

Comment: Convince yourself that "zero is the only non-negative real number which is less than every positive real number". If this does not sound trivial/obvious then replace the word "real" by "rational" and think again. Such statements are ultimately based on the fact that given a positive integer, there exists another larger positive integer (for example its successor).

Answer (score 1):

OK, I'll have a go at this. One of the problems with including more and more details is the tendency of the proof to become harder to follow, because it becomes more "trees" and less "forest".

We are to show that $\inf S = 0,$ where $S = \{1,\,\frac{1}{2},\,\frac{1}{3},\,\frac{1}{4},\,\frac{1}{5},\,\frac{1}{6},\,\ldots\}.$

We will show that $0 \leq \inf S$ and $\inf S \leq 0,$ which together implies that $\inf S = 0.$

**Proof that** $0 \leq \inf S$**:** $\;$ One of the properties of $\inf S$ is that if $L$ is a lower bound for $S,$ then $L \leq \inf S.$ Note that $0$ is a lower bound for $S,$ because $0$ is less than each of the elements that belongs to $S.$ Hence, it follows that $0 \leq \inf S.$

**Proof that** $\inf S \leq 0$**:** $\;$ We first show that $\inf S$ is less than each positive real number. To this end, let $\epsilon$ be a positive real number. Having chosen $\epsilon > 0,$ we now choose a specific positive integer $N$ so that $\frac{1}{N} < \epsilon.$ Note that $\frac{1}{N} \in S.$ Therefore (this being another property of $\inf S),$ we have $\inf S \leq \frac{1}{N}.$ From $\inf S \leq \frac{1}{N}$ and $\frac{1}{N} < \epsilon,$ it follows that $\inf S < \epsilon.$ We have now shown that $\inf S$ is less than each positive real number. Since we know that $\inf S$ exists and is a real number (i.e. not infinite), it follows that $\inf S \in (-\infty,\,0],$ because the only real numbers that are less than any positive real number are $0$ and negative real numbers. Since $\inf S \in (-\infty,\,0],$ we conclude that $\inf S \leq 0.$

Comment: I understood the proof in the picture very well. Except that why he said : "But since $\epsilon$ > 0 is arbitrary, it follows ..." it is not about $\epsilon$ at all. My proof is that since 1/n < any given $\epsilon$ , and 0 ≤ w ≤ 1/n   for all n , so w must be zero

Comment: *I understood the proof in the picture very well.* Then why say it is mistaken? It's not. *It is not about $\epsilon$ at all.* Yes, it is. The result would not follow if the inequality did not hold for *all* $\epsilon$. That is why they start with an arbitrary $\epsilon$, and *then* get $n$ from there, each $n$ depends on each $\epsilon$. *My proof is that...* No, $1/n$ is **not** less than any given $\epsilon$. For any given $\epsilon$ there exists some $n$ such that $1/n<\epsilon$. Hence, as $w$ is the infimum of $S$, we have $0 \leq w<\epsilon$. This is for all $\epsilon>0$, so $w=0$.

Comment: @Alex: As you probably realize, some of what your comment is concerned with is why I used $N$ (and not $n,$ which is used as a dummy variable elsewhere), and why I said "specific positive integer", and why I explicitly wrote $\frac{1}{N} \in S,$ and why I said "the only real numbers that are less than any positive real number". Of course, math_fun's comment came AFTER I included these various things . . .

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro Yes, my guess is the confusion is coming from what exactly the $n$ in the proof is doing there. You used $N$ instead, and I tried to focus on the important part of the inequality with $\epsilon$ showing how the $n$ is only a tool to get there. Hopefully one of our approaches will help clarify the misunderstanding, as $\epsilon$'s aren't going away any time soon in an analysis book!

Answer (score 0):

Another proof is as follows

Statement:
If $0 ≤ w < 1/n $ for every $n$, then $w=0$.

**Proof:**
Suppose for contrary that $w>0$. Then if we take $1/n_{0}=\frac{w}{2}$, then $0 <1/n_{0}<w$. Therefore, it is false that $w < 1/n$ for every $n$. we then say safely that $w=0$